# Faster zonal stats for equal rasters with Python

Tags: python, rasterio, rasterstats

I'm trying to extract data out of many raster images with different bounding boxes. Using the great `rasterstats.zonal_stats` it's a good approach, but it takes a considerable amount of time, especially for a large list of geometries. I wrote a small solution that works really fine for a set of raster files with equal bounds and resolution. Nonetheless, extending this to more complex scenarios, where rasters do not necessarily are equal (see image below)

[image: bounding boxes]

### Case A: raster images with equal bounds and resolution:

Looking at the source code behind `rasterstats`, the code iterates through each of the geometries passed to `zonal_stats` and use `rasterio.features.rasterize`, to mask the raster to the selected geometry and make the needed calculations. Despite being a robust approach it might be overacting when extracting > 100 rasters with similar metadata.

When a raster has the same metadata: same resolution, same boundaries
(bounding box), height, width, etc. It is possible to do the following:

#### 1. Create a crosswalk dictionary:

Store all the indices for each of the geometries using one of the rasters sources (again, here I have a list of identical rasters). Hence, the indices will be equal across all files.

```
with rasterio('path/to/raster/.tif') as src:
    with fiona.open(/path/to/shape, 'r') as shp:
        geoms = [feature['geometry'] for feature in shp]
        index = [feature['properties'][id_var] for feature in shp]

        crosswalk_dict = {}
        for idx, geom in zip(index, geoms):
            geom_rasterize = rasterize([(geom, 1)],
                                       out_shape=src.shape,
                                       transform=src.transform,
                                       all_touched=True,
                                       fill=0,
                                       dtype='uint8')

             crosswalk_dict[idx] = np.where(geom_rasterize == 1)
```

#### 2. Extract data

Loop through all the files and geometries in the crosswalk dictionary and calculate the mean using the source data for each of the files.

```
for path_raster in list_paths:
    with rasterio.open('/path/to/raster/.tif') as src:
     r_array = src.read(1)
     r_array[r_array == src.nodata] = np.nan

     mean_dict = {}
     for key, value in crosswalk_dict.items():
      mean_dict[key] = np.nanmean(r_array[value])

      df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(mean_dict,
        orient='index',
        columns=['mean'])
```

This process outputs similar results that `rasterstats.zonal_stats` means and it is quite fast since the rasterization is done only once. Nonetheless, in the image shown above, images have no similar `meta`. Each of the images has its own affine and boundaries, although they have the same resolution.

### Case B: raster images with different bounds:

In this case, I made a similar approach. All the functions in brackets are in [this](https://gist.github.com/ivanhigueram/fe37b26f43d68ad5e81f283b5f8d9ac7) gist. I didn't write them here for space readability issues, they're quite verbose.

1. Calculate an *envelope* boundary (the blue box in the image) (`draw_envelope`)
2. Give all files the bounds from the *envelope* built in step 1, but keeping the same data (`transform_raster_bounds`)
3. Now with "equal" files, create a crosswalk list using either a `meta` dict, or a file to create the dictionary (`get_crosswalk`)
4. Extract!

This is fine -I believe-, but somehow the results are incorrect, or not comparable to the ones made by `rasterstats`. I know this is a huge question, but I'm out of ideas on what can be wrong with the `transform_raster_bounds` function. Also, is this an overkill? There's a way to optimize `rasterstats`?

Comment: You might be interested to try `pygeoprocessing.zonal_statistics`, which minimizes the expensive rasterization step by calculating disjoint polygon sets first. Though I'm not sure if overlapping polygons are an issue for you. https://bitbucket.org/natcap/pygeoprocessing/src/develop/src/pygeoprocessing/geoprocessing.py